# Adding value labels on a bar chart using matplotlib

Tags: python, csv, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

When I print

```
graph_by_users = users.pivot(index='address', columns='used_at', values='users')
```

I get

```
              address  used_at   time online
0               am.ru     2014    114.741944
1               am.ru     2015     50.945000
2             auto.ru     2014   2533.983889
3             auto.ru     2015   1923.157500
4            avito.ru     2014  23473.097500
5            avito.ru     2015  24357.936389
6       avtomarket.ru     2014     29.680278
7       avtomarket.ru     2015     26.646389
8   cars.mail.ru/sale     2014     58.737778
9   cars.mail.ru/sale     2015     46.466111
10            drom.ru     2014   3059.709722
11            drom.ru     2015   2695.590000
12              e1.ru     2014   7966.210278
13              e1.ru     2015   7767.182500
14        irr.ru/cars     2014     61.720278
15        irr.ru/cars     2015     37.132778
```

I need to print bar chart

```
ax = graph_by_duration.plot.bar(width=0.5, ax=axes[0])
ax1 = graph_by_duration.plot.bar(width=0.8)
rects = ax1.patches
labels = ["%d" % i for i in time['time online']]
for rect, label in zip(rects, labels):
    height = rect.get_height()
    ax1.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2, height + 5, label,     
    ha='center', va='bottom')
```

[image: my_graph]
It put values to `2014` and after to `2015`. But it's wrong, because in my dataframe means are mixed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you've mixed up your labels. Try this:

```
ax = graph_by_duration.plot(kind='bar', width=0.5)
[label.set_rotation(25) for label in ax.get_xticklabels()]

labels = [int(round(graph_by_duration.loc[i, y]))
          for y in graph_by_duration.columns.tolist()
          for i in graph_by_duration.index]

for rect, label in zip(rects, labels):
    height = rect.get_height()
    ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2, height + 5, label,     
    ha='center', va='bottom', rotation=15)

plt.show()
```

[image]